# Android animation slows down

Tags: android, animation, performance

I have a continuous frame animation which runs 24 frames per X seconds, which is working fine, Now when i run another two animations ( Alpha animation ) at the same time , i notice  performance drop , that is frame animation slows down.

Any idea why this is happening, and is there any work around for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you code in inefficient and the phone can't handle it. If you provide the code I'm sure people can look over it and find where the inefficiencies might be.

Also, is this on a phone or the emulator?

Comment: thanks for replying. 

I have derived a class from AnimationDrawable and implemented some features to support callbacks. This class is used for frame animations. ( http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=128857303793437&topic=74 )

Next i have an xml file for alpha animation. I use following code to start the animation. 

mPulseView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha));

I have tested on both device and emulator, no much difference.

I need to know whether its possible to run multiple animations at same time in android without any performance drop.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using hardware layers to make your animation run smoothly.

You may have enabled hardware **acceleration** but that is not enough, you still need to use hardware **layers** on the views that you are animating get the best performance.

Use `view.setLayerType` to put the view into a hardware texture for the duration of the animation.

I just wrote a blog post about this, here: http://www.innodroid.com/blog/post/using-hardware-layers-for-complex-animations